# IE8 allows user to interact with elements obscured by modal window

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a pop-up, (what should be modal), dialogue for messages to the user (#modal). I've added a "background" element (#blinds) to obscure and prevent the user from interacting with other elements on the page. This works great in Firefox, not so much in IE8.

In IE8, I can click around, edit input fields, and submit the form. Is there a way to prevent this with HTML and CSS? Do I need a jQuery solution?

CSS;

```
#blinds {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#80000000, endColorstr=#80000000)";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#modal {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1001;
    display: none;
}
```

HTML;

```
<div id='blinds'></div>
<div id='modal'>
    <h1></h1>
    <span>X</span>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Here's a jsFiddle that illustrates my problem with IE8. http://jsfiddle.net/cAkzq/

Comment: Add a dummy click event to the overlay.

Comment: Adding a click and keypress handler on the overlay still allows me to click "under" it and interact with elements.

Comment: Not seeing this in a test jsFiddle.

Comment: use a click handler, not keypress. set the focus to the overlay to move the cursor off the elements below as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `-ms-filter` that is doing it. Use a semi-transparent PNG for your color overlay and it should fix the issue. Vendor tags are experimental and can be non-standard.