# "modal" div, interaction issues with content with IE8 transparent divs

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, modal-dialog, transparency

I am implementing a modal div and I have a problem with the interaction of a transparent div in IE.

I am using the following html and css for the modal div:

html:

```
<div id="content">
    hahahah
    <button>shouldn't be clickable</button>
</div>
<div id="modal">
    <div id="Alert">
        <div id="AlertText"></div>
        <button>OK</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#modal {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 1000000;
}
```

Indeed the div is transparent even in IE8, but the user can interact with the content below it such as, he can click the "shouldn't be clickable" button, which he shouldn't. Is there any solution to this?

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/T8kVh/

thank you in advance!

Comment: @Ligth, QVcool I KNOW how to make it TRANSPARENT. the problem is in IE8 the user can interact with content below the transparent div.

Comment: Ligth there is no point in offering unconstructive comments. if you READ the code you will see that I already am using the z-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Matthew Darnell on https://stackoverflow.com/a/9950641/2274855

> It's the -ms-filter that is doing it. Use a semi-transparent PNG for your color overlay and it should fix the issue. Vendor tags are experimental and can be non-standard.

Comment: i created a 1x1 transparent png which i included like this : background-image: url("trans.png"); just before the background-color statement and it seems to do the trick